# Format query logs using Spring Logback

Tags: logging, logback

Is there a way to format query log output using only Logback?

I am using JPA, Mybatis for queries.
JPA query logs are formatted but Mybatis queries are logged just oneline. I want Mybatis query logs to be formatted in multi-lines like JPA query logs so that I can see better.

```
Mybatis query logs)
==>  Preparing: /* selectABC */ SELECT a, b, c FROM t_table WHERE a = ? AND b = ?

JPA query logs)
select
       a,
       b,
       c
from   t_table
where  a = 1
       and b = 1
Hibernate:
select
        a as a_1
        b as b_1
        and so on
```

I know using log4j I can format Mybatis query logs multi-line too but I want to know first if there is a way  by only changing Logback settings

searched stackoverflow